# How can I display image uploaded in Angular and get the filepath in ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

When I edit my data with image, I can't get the file path in my back end how can I access the file path in ASP.NET Core MVC to Angular?

This is my HTML - I want to view the uploaded image in imageURL.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <button mat-raised-button class="photo" (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload Image <mat-icon>add_photo_alternate</mat-icon></button>
        <input hidden (change)="onFileSelected($event)" #fileInput type="file" id="formFile" formControlName="photo"> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <img [src]="imageURL " *ngIf="imageURL" style="height: 150px; width: 278px">
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my typescript in Angular:

```
if (this.editData) {
    this.actionBtn = "Update";
    this.selectedCategoryId = this.editData.categoryId;
    this.getItemSubCategoryList();
    this.propertyForm.controls['id'].setValue(this.editData.id);
    this.propertyForm.controls['isActive'].setValue(this.editData.isActive);                        
    this.propertyForm.controls['propertyNo'].setValue(this.editData.propertyNo);
    this.propertyForm.controls['appNo'].setValue(this.editData.appNo);
    this.propertyForm.controls['propertyName'].setValue(this.editData.propertyName);
    this.propertyForm.controls['categoryId'].setValue(this.editData.categoryId);
    this.propertyForm.controls['subCategoryId'].setValue(this.editData.subCategoryId);
    this.propertyForm.controls['brand'].setValue(this.editData.brand);
    this.propertyForm.controls['uomId'].setValue(this.editData.uomId);
    this.propertyForm.controls['warehouseId'].setValue(this.editData.warehouseId);
    this.propertyForm.controls['propertyType'].setValue(this.editData.propertyType);
    this.propertyForm.controls['model'].setValue(this.editData.model);
    this.propertyForm.controls['quantity'].setValue(this.editData.quantity);
    this.propertyForm.controls['supplierId'].setValue(this.editData.supplierId);
    this.propertyForm.controls['photo'].setValue(this.editData.photo);
    console.log(this.propertyForm)
}
```

This is my controller in ASP.NET Core MVC :

I want to get the filepath in EF Core to Angular this is my filepath `@"StaticFiles\Uploaded\PropertyImages\"`

```
[HttpPut("Edit")]
public async Task<ActionResult<PropertyItemsDTO>> Edit([FromForm] PropertyItemsDTO item)
{
    var data = new PropertyItemsDTO();
    var itemindb = await _PropertyItemsRepository.UpdateValidateExistingItem(item.PropertyNo, item.Id);

    if (itemindb == null)
        return NotFound();
        
    if (item.Photo == null)
    {
        return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
    }

    string targetPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath, @"StaticFiles\Uploaded\PropertyImages\");
    // if propertyItemId is not empty, get the image file name from DB
    // check the file if it exist in the image repository,
    // if file found/exist then delete it
    if (item.Id != null)
    {
        // get the image file name from DB
        string imageInDB = _PropertyItemsRepository.GetPropertyImageFileName(item.Id);

        if (imageInDB != null)
             if (imageInDB != "")
             {
                 filePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, imageInDB);
                 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);

                 if (file.Exists) // check the file if it exist in the image repository
                     file.Delete(); //if file found/exist then delete it
             }
         }

         IFormFile formFile = item.Photo;
         string fileName = "";

         if (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg") //Change the file type according to the business rule
         {
             fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "" + Path.GetExtension(formFile.FileName);
             string filePath = Path.Combine(targetPath, fileName);
        
             using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
             {
                 formFile.CopyTo(stream);
             }

             item.ImageURL = fileName;

             return Ok(await _PropertyItemsRepository.Update(item));
         }
         else
             return new UnsupportedMediaTypeResult();
     }
}
```

Comment: EF Core **doesn't** have controllers - ASP.NET Core MVC does. EF Core the **data access** technology - executing Linq queries and such - but it's **NOT** the web framework - that would be **ASP.NET Core MVC** ....

Comment: what should i do @marc_s